# E ink hat for Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: pi-4, display, eink

Is there any E ink display hat for the Raspberry Pi 4? I have been searching for a while but can't seem to find one.

Comment: A simple google gave me  https://www.sossolutions.nl/264x176-2-7inch-e-ink-display-hat-for-raspberry-pi-three-color Ah well, perhaps SOS solutions is in my google-bubble and not in yours.

Comment: @Ljm Dullaart Thanks for the link! I think for regional google sites, it didn’t show up for me.

Comment: What about the Pimoroni or Adafruit ones?  As this is not a shopping channel (see usage notes https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic point 3 off-topic) I'm voting close rather than give a formal answer.

Comment: @Andyroo Thanks for the close vote   Will they work on Pi 4? I just saw this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/4143 & Pi 4 is not in there.

Comment: Shhh - I may get slapped :-) https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/inky-what?variant=13590497624147 states *Compatible with all 40-pin header Raspberry Pi models* but I know some folk have issues with some HATs as they hardware moves from Pi to Pi.  There is https://technicallyrural.ca/2020/06/08/inky-what-with-raspberry-pi-4/ but I think the best thing is to drop the guys at Pimoroni a mail or forum message as messages are very mixed (e.g. https://thepihut.com/products/inky-what-epaper-eink-epd says headers for Pi 4 but then does not list it)!

Comment: LAST point - check recent vids from Adafruit / forums as concerns are being voiced on the number of refreshes per hour possible before e-ink fails.  They are not fast devices and I'm moving back to OLED style displays for some devices.

Comment: @Andyroo Thanks a lot for the details. Will mail at Pimoroni 